# Best way to serialize list of Java objects into yaml with 2 line breaks separating each generated top level object node

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, formatting, yaml

Currently, I can convert a list of Java objects into a yaml String like so:

```
private static final ObjectMapper YAML_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
private static final ObjectWriter YAML_WRITER = YAML_MAPPER.writer();

public static String toYamlString(Object value) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String s = YAML_WRITER.writeValueAsString(value);
}
```

This generates valid yaml but generates the yaml like so

```
---
- dogs: "dalmatians"
  items:
  - "rover"
  - "spot"
  - "sir barksalot"
  hungry: true
- instruction: "fetch bone"
  condition: "bone is thrown"
  response: "retrieve bone"
```

Instead I would the yaml to be generated like the below with an additional linebreak separating dogs and instruction:

```
---
- dogs: "dalmatians"
  items:
  - "rover"
  - "spot"
  - "sir barksalot"
  hungry: true

- instruction: "fetch bone"
  condition: "bone is thrown"
  response: "retrieve bone"
```

I'm currently using Jackson, but none of the serialization features seem related to this functionality. I am open to using a different library, but it must be Java.

I attempted to use MinimalPrettyPrinter like the below, but it does not appear to work

```
    public static String toYamlString(Object value) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String s = YAML_WRITER.with(new MinimalPrettyPrinter() {

            @Override
            public void writeEndObject(JsonGenerator g, int nrOfEntries) throws IOException
            {
                g.writeRaw('}');
                g.writeRaw('\n');
            }
        }).writeValueAsString(value);
        return s;
    }
```

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with YAML (forgive my ignorance), but are `dogs` and `instruction` root values? If so, you should be able to achieve what you want by instantiating a `MinimalPrettyPrinter` using the `rootValuesSeparator` constructor argument (without needing to override any methods of the printer; no anonymous class). Also, I recommend using `System.lineSeparator()` to ensure you're using the proper line termination for your platform.

Comment: @VinceEmigh `PrettyPrinter` is used for JSON, not for YAML (see [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter.html): *Pretty printers are used to add white space in output JSON content*). YAML uses whitespace as syntax element and therefore cannot use the same pretty printer.